# Duplicate std::cin in C++

Tags: c++, linux

Is C++ cin a file descriptor and is possible to duplicate using dup()? I want to duplicate the standard input in order to use one for filestream using redirection from the shell and one is for regular input after getting all the input from the file.

Answer (score 3):

No.

std::cin is an [input stream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/). This is a C++ concept that *may* under the scenes be implemented using (in part) a file handle. However, all you have access to is the stream object and its members.

Answer (score 3):

`std::cin` is bound to standard input file descriptor, in POSIX world it is defined as `STDIN_FILENO` and its value is usually 0. `std::cin` is just a special `std::istream` to read from that descriptor. You can use `dup` to duplicate it - no problem, you don't have to use `std::cin` for this purpose at all.

Comment: So, Can I reassign cin after getting input from my shell with my coppied fd? i.e. ./MyProgram < MyFile will switch cin into fstream (if I remember correctly) and there's no way to turn back.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to duplicate the stream, just create an `fstream` and read the data need.

Comment: The problem is I must get input from shell redirection like: ./MyProgram < myfile . However, this is not required, but I still want to let user be able to input.

Comment: @Amumu: If you're using shell redirection, the `dup` operation happens transparently at the shell level, and you don't need to worry about it. Just keep reading from STDIN using `std::cin` and your program won't know (and won't need to know) if it's reading from a file or from user interaction.

Comment: I don't know the way to get two inputs from shell, probably you just need to pass a file name as a cmdline argument?